# Torque PBS passing environment variables that contain quotes

Tags: bash, pbs, quoting, torque

I have a python script.  Normally I would run this like this:

```
./make_graph data_directory "wonderful graph title"
```

I have to run this script through the scheduler.  I am using -v to pass the arguments for the python script through qsub.

```
qsub make_graph.pbs -v ARGS="data_directory \"wonderful graph title\""
```

I have tried many combinations of ', ", \" escaping and I just can't get it right.  The quoting around 'wonderful graph title' is always either lost or mangled.

Here is an excerpt from the pbs script

```
if [ -z "${ARGS+xxx}" ]; then
        echo "NO ARGS SPECIFIED!"
        exit 1
fi

CMD="/path/make_graph $ARGS"
echo "CMD: $CMD"

echo "Job started on `hostname` at `date`"
${CMD}
```

What is the proper way to pass a string parameter that contains spaces through qsub as an environment variable?  Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe this is a more general bash problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This answer is based on SGE `qsub` rather than TORQUE `qsub`, so the CLI is somewhat different. In particular, TORQUE `qub` doesn't seem to support direct argument passing, so the second approach doesn't work.

---

This is mainly a problem of proper quoting and has little to do with grid engine submission itself. If you just want to fix your current script, you should use `eval "${CMD}"` rather than `${CMD}`. Here's a detailed analysis of what happens when you do `${CMD}` alone (in the analysis we assume there's nothing funny in `path`):

1. Your `qsub` command line is processed and quotes removed, so the `ARGS` environment variable passed is `data_directory "wonderful graph title"`.
2. You did `CMD="/path/make_graph $ARGS"`, so the value of `CMD` is `/path/make_graph data_directory "wonderful graph title"` (I'm presenting the string literal without quoting, that is, the value literally contains the quote characters).
3. You did `${CMD}`. Bash performs a parameter expansion on this, which amounts to:

   1. Expanding `${CMD}` to its value `/path/make_graph data_directory "wonderful graph title"`;
   2. Since `${CMD}` is not quoted, perform word splitting, so in the end the command line has five words: `/path/make_graph`, `data_directory`, `"wonderful`, `graph`, `title"`. The last four are treated as arguments to your `make_graph`, which is certainly not what you want.

On the other hand, if you use `eval "${CMD}"`, then it is as if you typed `/path/make_graph data_directory "wonderful graph title"` into an interactive shell, which is the desired behavior.

You should read more about `eval`, parameter expansion, etc. in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

The corrected script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -z ${ARGS+xxx} ]] && { echo "NO ARGS SPECIFIED!" >&2; exit 1; }

CMD="/path/make_graph ${ARGS}"
echo "CMD: ${CMD}"

echo "Job started on $(hostname) at $(date)" # backticks are deprecated
eval "${CMD}"
```

By the way, to test this, you don't need to submit it to the grid engine; just do

```
ARGS="data_directory \"wonderful graph title\"" bash make_graph.pbs
```

---

Okay, I just pointed out what's wrong and patched it. But is it really the "proper way" to pass arguments to grid engine jobs? No, I don't think so. Arguments are arguments, and should not be confused with environment variables. `qsub` allows you to pass arguments directly (`qsub` synopsis: `qsub [ options ] [ command | -- [ command_args ]]`), so why encode them in an env var and end up worrying about quoting?

Here's a better way to write your submission script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ $# == 0 ]] && { echo "NO ARGS SPECIFIED!" >&2; exit 1; }

CMD="/path/make_graph $@"
echo "CMD: ${CMD}"

echo "Job started on $(hostname) at $(date)" # backticks are deprecated
/path/make_graph "$@"
```

Here `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...` — faithfully passing all arguments as is (see [relevant section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0040) in the Bash Reference Manual).

One thing unfortunate about this, though, is that although the command executed is correct, the one printed may not be properly quoted. For instance, if you do

```
qsub make_graph.pbs data_directory "wonderful graph title"
```

then what gets executed is `make_graph.pbs data_directory "wonderful graph title"`, but the printed `CMD` is `make_graph.pbs data_directory wonderful graph title`. And there's no easy way to fix this, as far as I know, since quotes are always removed from arguments no matter how word splitting is done. If the command printed is really important to you, there are two solutions:

1. Use a dedicated "shell escaper" (pretty easy to write one for yourself) to quote the arguments before printing;
2. Use another scripting language where shell quoting is readily available, e.g., Python (`shlex.quote`) or Ruby (`Shellwords.shellescape`).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.  I wish it were correct.  I am trying the patch you suggested.  Unfortunately while it works correctly with the bash test method you suggest, the quotes are still being stripped when run with the scheduler.

Comment: when I print args using the bash method, the quotes are preserved.  when I print them using qsub, they're gone.  So it's being stripped out before being added to CMD

#!/bin/bash

echo $0
USAGE="USAGE: qsub make_graph.pbs -v ARGS=\"...\""

if [ ! -z "${PBS_O_WORKDIR+xxx}" ]; then
        cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
fi

[[ -z ${ARGS+xxx} ]] && { echo "NO ARGS SPECIFIED!" >&2; exit 1; }

echo "ARGS: ${ARGS}"
echo "build command"
CMD="/path/make_graph.py ${ARGS}"
echo "CMD: ${CMD}"

Comment: unless I am still calling this incorrectly

bash test

 ARGS="/path/ \"wonderful title\"" bash make_graph.pbs

scheduler test

qsub make_graph.pbs -v ARGS="/path/ \"wonderful title\""

Comment: That's unexpected, but honestly I don't use the `-v` option frequently, and certainly don't use it for passing arguments. Could you give me a few minutes to look at this issue (my queue is pretty jammed at the moment)? In the mean time, could you give my second script a spin? It's the more natural way to pass arguments.

Comment: I appreciate the help. No hurry.  I've burnt too much time on this so I am just going to use _'s instead of spaces for now.

Comment: Wait a second, I just noticed that you are calling `qsub` the wrong way. You should use `qsub -v ARGS="data_directory \"wonderful graph title\"" make_graph.pbs`. All options after your script file are taken as arguments to your script, rather than options to `qsub`.

Comment: And my local tests say my submission script works correctly when you call `qsub` the correct way.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't make a difference here.  I am on version 3.03 of torque pbs though, might be a bug.  The current is 4.27 I think.

Calling this as 
qsub -v ARGS="data_directory \"wonderful title\"" make_graph.pbs

Comment: looking at the changelog for torque, https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque/blob/master/CHANGELOG#L303 looks like this may have been fixed in 4.2.0  I am going to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Hmm crap. I'm exercising my knowledge of `qsub` from SGE here and I thought the interfaces would be the same, but it seems that they are somewhat different. And the change log entry makes it pretty clear that quoting in value simply won't work in your old version :(

Comment: I read the TORQUE PBS `qsub` man page, and unfortunately it doesn't support direct argument passing (unlike SGE `qsub`). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: By the way, since `ARGS` doesn't work, I think you'd better take the `param1=value1,param2=value2,...` approach, i.e., use `-v directory=some_directory,title=some_title`, and parse `$directory` and `$title` in your submission script.